# Hide/show tab dependant on Craft sites

Tags: craft3, field, sections, multi-site

I have multiple sites, in a Field Layout of section entry type, I have tab A and tab B. I want tab A to show in site A, but hide it(including all the fields under it) in site B. Is there a way to achieve that? thanks

If can not do it in craft3, dose craft cms 4 has this feature?

Answer (score 2):

Craft 4 introduces Conditions. Maybe this is what you are searching for.

- https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/conditions.html